# How do I make Yahoo recognise my DKIM keys as DomainKeys

Tags: email, dkim, domainkeys

My outbound email is working correctly with DKIM, and I"d like to thet the lock icon next for my yahoo recipients.

Since DKIM is the new DomainKeys, what can I do to enable what seems to be a DomainKeys only technology within the Yahoo web mail client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo does not generate the lock/key icon if the mail is signed with DKIM but not with DomainKeys.

If you really want the lock/key icon, sign the mail with DomainKeys as well.

If you're using Sendmail or Postfix, dk-filter should do the job quite nicely. It runs as a milter.

If you use both DKIM and DK, make sure that the DK signature is performed first. The reason for this is that DK does not self-sign the header, and DKIM does. Having the DK signature signed by the DKIM signature therefore bypasses the problem of DK's lack of self signature.

Ie, if, for example you are using OpenDKIM to sign with DKIM, make sure that the mail is passed through dk-filter and then OpenDKIM.

All that said, other than the lock/key icon in the older version of Yahoo's UI, there's no advantage to using DK and DKIM when compared to just using DKIM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mDaemon then this Knowledge base article is all that's required for [configuring DKIM in mDaemon](http://www.altn.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/KnowledgeBaseResults/?Number=KBA-02067).

For Yahoo, all I did was click the option in mDaemon to sign outgoing emails with DomainKeys (right next to the DKIM option) too. I didn't do anything else.